# Why does my Javascript File not load into html after I use $sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='boo'></div>");

Tags: angularjs, vexflow

I am trying to load Vexflow sheetmusic into Div Dynamically through angularja `ng-bind-html` with `$sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='boo'></div>")`. This Works With `$sce.trustAsHtml("<p>Hello World</p>")`. Putting `<div id='boo'></div>` in body of page works also. It will not load sheet music into div with ng-bind-html with `$sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='boo'></div>")`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9  /angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vexflow/releases/vexflow-debug.js">                                         </script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</div>

<script>
```

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $sce) {
$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='boo'></div>");
});

id = "boo";
len =window.innerWidth/2;
VF = Vex.Flow;
// Create an SVG renderer and attach it to the DIV element named "boo".
var div = document.getElementById(id);
var renderer = new VF.Renderer(div, VF.Renderer.Backends.SVG);

// Size our svg:
renderer.resize(window.innerWidth/2 , 200);

// And get a drawing context:
var context = renderer.getContext();
// Create a stave at position 0, 40 of width of 'len' on the canvas.
var stave = new VF.Stave(0, 40, len);

// Add a clef and time signature.
stave.addClef("treble").addTimeSignature("4/4");

// Connect it to the rendering context and draw!
stave.setContext(context).draw();
```

```
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `document.getElementById` function executes before the AngularJS framework `ng-bind-html` adds the element with the ID of  `boo` to the DOM.

Comment: How does one go about getting the desired results. I would like the JS file to load after angular.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the JS file to load after angular.

For code attached to an element, use a custom directive:

```
app.directive("booDirective", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        var div = elem[0];
        var renderer = new VF.Renderer(div, VF.Renderer.Backends.SVG);
        //...
    }
});
```

### Usage

```
<div boo-directive></div>
```

When the AngularJS framework compiles DOM, it invokes the link function of any attached directives.

**Note:** The `ng-bind-html` does not compile added DOM. However core directives such as `ng-include`, `ng-view`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, etc. compile templates before adding them to the DOM.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

This works now. I had my own errors. Thanks for help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vexflow/releases/vexflow-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div boo-directive></div>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive("booDirective", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
    var len =window.innerWidth/2;
    var VF = Vex.Flow;
        var div = elem[0];
        var renderer = new VF.Renderer(div, VF.Renderer.Backends.SVG);
    // Size our svg:
    renderer.resize(window.innerWidth/2 , 200);

    // And get a drawing context:
    var context = renderer.getContext();
    // Create a stave at position 0, 40 of width of 'len' on the canvas.
    var stave = new VF.Stave(0, 40, len);

    // Add a clef and time signature.
    stave.addClef("treble").addTimeSignature("4/4");

    // Connect it to the rendering context and draw!
    stave.setContext(context).draw();
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```